# SQL запрос для двух связанных таблиц

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть 3 таблицы в бд.

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `categories`
--

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Структура таблицы `category_position`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_position` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_position` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Структура таблицы `positions`
    --

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `positions` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Пытаюсь добавить в две связанные строчки в одном запросе:

```
INSERT INTO positions (title) VALUES ('$_POST[title]'); SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID() INSERT INTO category_position (id_category,id_position) VALUES ('$_POST[category]', @id);
```

Это запрос проверял в phpMyAdmin, работает, но когда я пишу его в php

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO positions (title) VALUES ('$_POST[title]'); SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO category_position (id_category,id_position) VALUES ('$_POST[category]', @id)")){
```

то в условии `false` и ни в одну из таблиц ничего не добавляется, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Твоя проблема в том, что ты шлешь сразу несколько запросов. Из офф. мануала:

```
mysql_query() посылает один запрос (посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается) активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный дескриптор link_identifier.
```

Тебе нужно или разбить запрос на 3 раза или же использовать [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php).

**P.S.**

1. За такое `VALUES ('$_POST[title]');` можно получить по голове. Всё сначала нужно эскейпить, то есть проверять все входящие данные на предмет запрещенных символов, так как у тебя взломают на раз-два.
2. Функция mysql_query и ему подобные считаются устаревшими, посему их использовать не рекомендуется: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php