# Объединяем два запроса в multi query

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть 3 таблицы из вот этого [поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382686/php-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86).

Хочу достать из `positions` строки `id`, которых в таблице `category_position` связаны с определённым id из `categories`.

Сейчас я делаю это вот так:

```
$result_id_position = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id_position FROM category_position WHERE id_category = '$_GET[category]'");
        $id_position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_id_position);

        if (empty($id_position[0])) {
            $positions = "null";
        } else {
            $positions = array();
            do {
                $result_position = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM positions WHERE id = '$id_position[0]'");
                $position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_position);

                echo $position[2];
                );

            } while ($id_position = mysqli_fetch_row($result_id_position));
            $result_position->close();
        }
        $result_id_position->close();
```

Возможно ли заменить два запроса одним мульти и избавится от первого цикла, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, таблица `categories` здесь и не нужна. Поэтому данные можно получить в таком виде:

```
SELECT
    positions.*,
    positions.id IS NULL AS is_absent
FROM category_position

LEFT JOIN positions
ON category_position.id_position = positions.id

WHERE category_position.id_category = $_GET[category]
```

А дальше по полю `is_absent` определяете есть позиции или нет. Вместо `is_absent` можно проверять по `id`, но так нагляднее.

Comment: Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a5f/2)